# Rails devise redirecting to '/users' instead of '/users/sign_up' on failed registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've been searching all over to fix this - when a user fails a registration create using Devise, for whatever reason they get redirected to '/users' instead of staying on '/users/sign_up' and persisting the errors:

Here are my routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions:       'users/sessions',
  confirmations:  'users/confirmations',
  registrations:  'users/registrations',
  passwords:      'users/passwords',
  invitations:    'users/invitations'
}, sign_out_via: [:get, :delete]
```

And `/users/registrations_controller.rb`

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @body_class = "hold-transition register-page"
    build_resource({})
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
  end

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

If the resource is not persisted, in the spot where it says render :new I've tried the following:

`redirect_to new_user_registration_path(resource)` - does not persist errors

`render :new` - routes to '/users' but does persist errors

`respond_with resource` - does same as :new

`respond_with resource, location: new_user_registration_path(resource)` - again same as above

So if the resource doesn't persist how can I get it to just go back to the same page - '/users/sign_up' and persist the errors? I've seen some very hacky ways but there's no way Devise doesn't offer a solution for this instead of forcing it to route to '/users'. I've also seen solutions that include a redirect and setting a flash - this is not something I want to do, I'd rather the errors persist in the form.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, im assuming you want to go back if registration fails?

you can use:

```
redirect_to :back
```

And in your code like this:

```
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  render :new
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: [My question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227666/why-does-devise-redirect-sign-up-error-to-a-different-page) is very similar. Can you help me, please?